# Azure Websites - set a custom domain but leave email at the original hosting

Tags: azure, web, dns

Anyone knows how to do it? It seems that domain emails will stop working as per warning on the  hosting site...

"I am aware and accept that all current DNS settings, e-mail addresses, and forwards will be disabled."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a CNAME record should have no effect on the rest of your DNS settings (like MX records, used for email). Where are you seeing that message?

Comment: it is on my 1and1 hosting provider, on the edit DNS settings page. i was trying to attach a screenshot but apparently can not yet... but thanks for the info. i will verify it with the provider.